# mongodb query issue for contructing where clause

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I am completely new to mongoDB,I have this below query:

```
jds=jd.aggregate( [
   {
     "$group": {
        "_id": {"house_NAME":"$house_NAME"},
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
     }
   },
   { "$match": { "count": { "$gt": 0 } } }
   ] )
```

which returns count of each house name present in the collection.

my collection is somewhat like below :

```
record_id  house_NAME  status

1          Thomas    Open
2          Panther   Close
3          Thomas    Close
```

what I want is to only return the value whose status is "Open", I want to add "and" clause in above query so it return the count of only those documents whose status "Open". I don't know how exactly to do it.

I am stucked in it .any help will be greatly appreciated !

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2):

You can add a [**`$match`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) stage at the start of the pipeline

```
jds=jd.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "status": "Open" }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": { "house_NAME": "$house_NAME" },
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }
  }},
 { "$match": { "count": { "$gt": 0 }}}
])
```